# Parse.com Error 3840

Tags: json, parse-platform

I get this error when I try to retrieve items from Parse.com 
In 10 attempts it failed around 6 times.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ServiceCatalogue"];
items  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

         NSLog(@"ServiceCatalogue  retrieved");

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

And getting error:

> "Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)
>   UserInfo=0x7fcfbaadc480 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.} {
>           NSDebugDescription = "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.";
>       }"

Comment: I beleive parse.com servers are bit down for the moment and they send false response. Instead of sending some JSON to the API they send something else so the API itself throws the error. Take it as an opportunity to test your code if it is "parse" safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in this status report from Parse, it looks like their servers were creating an elevated number of errors.

[2nd October 2015 - Elevated Error Rates - Incident Report for Parse](https://status.parse.com/incidents/kd27r5fg84y8)